# Task class issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task

i am trying to implement task class in windows phone 8.1 app. In my app the task is to know that whether user has pressed the back key, completed the task or failure occured due to network. for this i am using continue with () method of task class. dont know what the issue. help me in it .

code:

```
  await GetData(limit, offset).ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("task completed");

                        result = t.Result;
                        //throw new Exception("task 2 error");
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion).ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("task fault");
                        //throw new Exception("task 2 error");
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine("task cancelled");
                        //throw new Exception("task 2 error");
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

                 );
```

i dont know what's the issue so kindly help required.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ContinueWith` if you have access to `async`/`await`. It's that simple. `ContinueWith` will let you do all the same things as the new keyword, but is far harder to read, understand, use well and maintain. So do yourself a favor and don't use it unless you really *really* have to.

Your code becomes

```
try
{
    result = await GetData(limit, offset);
}
catch(TaskCancelledException)
{
    // GetData has been cancelled
    // Console.WriteLine("task cancelled");
    //throw new Exception("task 2 error");
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //GetData has been faulted
    //Console.WriteLine("task fault");
    //throw new Exception("task 2 error");
}
```

Now it is far easier to understand what you mean to do.

**edit**

A further clarification seems needed here. Using the `await` keywords fundamentally is the same as using `ContinueWith`. It just allows you to write complex asynchronous logic in a much more concise and easy to read way.

```
async Task DoAsyncWork()
{
    var a = await GetAAsync();
    Frob(a);
}
```

is exactly the same as

```
//Notice there is no async keword here
Task DoAsyncWork()
{
    return GetAAsync().ContinueWith(t => Frob(t.Result),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

Similarly, a `try/catch` block with an `await` inside is equivalent to a fairly complicated expression with `ContinueWith`, `TaskContinuationOptions` and `AggregateException` unwrapping.
It gets much more complex if you add the possibility of chaining two or more `Tasks`, or some `if` here and there, and some loops for good measure (`for`, `foreach` or `while`, it does not really matter). if you stick to your `ContinueWith` guns you get the kind of code that no sane man would like to write. And that's ok, because it's the compiler's job to write it for you. And the compiler is not a sane man. So just stick to àwait`as long as you can.

If you can't use `async/await` (clearly not your case, you're programming for WP8), it's okay to weep, because you're in for a lot of potential hurt. Some extension methods would make your life easier, but it still won't be pretty.

Comment: I know but its a requirement which needs to be catered. for instance if a person presses back button , network disconnects, failure in operation . if any of such situation arises then my app should respond according to that particular situation.

Comment: Yes the app should react accordingly. But i don't see how it's relevant here. The code I wrote in my response has the exact same semantics as the code in the original answer, and will react to a cancellation or an error by passing the control to the appropriate catch block. You don't need `ContinueWith`. The only case where it differs is if getData was faulted with a `TaskCancelationException`... and that feels very wrong to me!